# Find out webroot in running apache 2

Tags: unix, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I am running an Apache Server and tried to change the webroot from a default location to my specific one, by chaning the path in `sites-enabled`. However, it does not work  as expected and now, if I navigate to localhost, I get a 403.

Can I find out which Directory on my (running) Apache server is taken as my webroot?

(It's not the default value and not the specific one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more details, a possible approach is to use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) like this :

```
grep -r DocumentRoot /etc/{apache,http}* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what the `httpd.conf` says. 
A common default for `httpd.conf` is in `/etc/httpd/conf`. 
A common default for webroot is in `/var/www`.